Why does my map have exclamation points marked on it?
I have just started playing and some locations on my compass have an exclamation point marked and I have no idea what this is telling me. I have highlighted it below.

What are these exclamation points denoting on my map?

They mean things that your pawns have pointed out, have said, have commented on it. Be it a ladder, an item to be read, a Seeker's Coin, etc...
Sources:

https://www.reddit.com/r/DragonsDogma/comments/1bkb6ie/
https://gamerant.com/dragons-dogma-2-exclamation-mark-point-map-meaning-dd/
https://www.gamesradar.com/dragons-dogma-2-exclamation-mark-point/

Edit, Shows up as a tip screen too

